# Missing Operator, SQL

Tags: sql, operators, syntax-error, ms-access-2010

I can't seem to find where I'm missing an operator. I've looked at this many times, I tried signle quotes, double quotes, checked field names, I'm outta options.

Here is how "SQL1" is being created, this runs fine.

```
SELECT ID, Result, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 G WHERE G.Result <> GR.Result AND G.ID <= GR.ID) AS RunGroup FROM Table1 AS GR;
```

Here is how "SQL2" is being created, this also runs fine.

```
SELECT Result, MIN(ID) AS StartID, MAX(ID) AS EndID, COUNT(*) AS Games FROM SQL1 AS A GROUP BY Result, RunGroup ORDER BY Min(ID);
```

When it comes to this query, is says syntax error, missing operator, then highlights "Result".

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM SQL2 A ORDER BY Games, WHERE Result = "W";
```

Suggestions?

Comment: `WHERE Result = "W" ORDER BY Games;`  in other words take out the comma and switch the 'where' and 'order by clauses'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM SQL2 A WHERE Result = 'W' ORDER BY Games;
```